# Audit Trail VS Event monitoring

Tags: logging, eventlogfile, setup-audit-log

what are the difference between Audit Trail and Event monitoring? Which informations can I retrieve from one and from another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Audit Trail](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_monitorsetup.htm&type=5) simply shows basic things like when an administrator modifies a page layout or creates a new user; basically it only tracks changes that are made in the Setup menu (or the SOAP/REST/Metadata/Tooling APIs when they modify items in Setup).

Event Monitoring tracks practically every single thing a user does, including API calls, running reports, and so on. The full list of supported types for Event Monitoring is listed [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm), and has almost 50 different types of events you can report on.

Comment: Audit Trail runs passively while to enable event monitoring an action from a user is needed, correct?